# Show images on form with corresponding result name of the database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

First of all I have a small database in Access with 2 fields (id excluded): firstname and lastname. To use this data I have a simpel form where I use the 2 fields (first- and lastname), but also an image. The image is a picture of that person, but here sits my problem. I'm kinda new to Access.

I have a folder with an image of all the persons, but how can I access these picture in access for the form. I want for every record on the form the correct picture (from the folder) of that person.

E.g.:

Record 1: Georgie Access -> must show the image of Georie Access.jpg
Record 2: Gabbie Donald -> image of Gabbie Donald.jpg

To make it easy I would like to combine the firstname and lastname field to built the image filename. The extention is always a jpg.

I hope the question is a bit clear.

Comment: There are at least three ways to do what you want. One option is to develop a naming scheme for the images that matches the First & Last name fields. A second option is to add a field (or a related table) to your table and populate that with the path & filename of the image. A third option is to use the 'Attachment' data type and add a field to your table and store the image in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your form view is *Single Form* and not *Datasheet* as it's not possible to display an image in a datagrid in "standard" MS Access

1. Add an **Image** control to your form and name it for instance "ThePhoto"
2. In the "*On Current*" event of your form, add this code to change the image path when the Form's current record changes:

   Private Sub Form_Current()

   ```
   ThePhoto.Picture = "C:/PathToPictures/" & firstname & " " & lastname & ".jpg"
   ```

   End Sub

Can't give more details with what's in the question.